# a login form error + JDBC CONNECTIVITY(JAVA-MYSQL)

Tags: java, mysql

I have a project with JDBC connectivity (JAVA-MYSQL)  which has a login up form. But the coding doesn't work.(meaning it always shows "WRONG PASSWORD" though I'm  sure its the right one).

Please find the error. (cause it shows none).

```js
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  String S;
  String email = jTextField3.getText();
  try {
    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:Mysql://localhost/nami", "root", "123456");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    S = "SELECT password FROM signup WHERE email =" + "'" + email + "'" + ";";
    st.executeQuery(S);

    String pass = new String(jPasswordField2.getPassword());

    if (pass.equals("S")) {
      jOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU HAVE SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN");
      MAINPAGE at = new MAINPAGE();
      jDesktopPane1.add(at);
      at.show();

    } else {
      jOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(null, "WRONG PASSWORD!!");
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    jOptionPane2.showMessageDialog(null, "Error" + e.getMessage());
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pass.equals("S")` means that your password should always be `S` in order to log in success.

You need to query from the database and then compare it.

```
Result rs = st.executeQuery(S);
String queryPass = null;
if(rs.next()){
   queryPass = rs.getString("password");
}

if (pass.equals(queryPass)) {
  jOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU HAVE SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN");
  MAINPAGE at = new MAINPAGE();
  jDesktopPane1.add(at);
  at.show();

} else {
  jOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(null, "WRONG PASSWORD!!");
}
```

BTW,it's a bad idea to pass parameters directly into your sql,you need to use **[PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)** instead of **[Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)** to avoid **SQL Injection**

Answer (score 0):

## Try This ##

```
 String email=request.getParameter("email");
   String pass=request.getParameter("pass");



                     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users_record","root","root");
                     Statement st1=con.createStatement();
                     ResultSet obj1=st1.executeQuery("select * from registration where email='" +email+ "'");

                     System.out.println(email);        
                     while(obj1.next())
                        {

                             String p2=obj1.getString(5);
                             if(p2.equals(pass))
                                 {

                                     response.sendRedirect("home1.jsp?msg=YOU HAVE SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN ");


                                 }
                             else
                                 {
                                       response.sendRedirect("login1.jsp?msg=Invalid password");
                                 }
                        }
```